I would like to understand the example given in the mix-blend-mode specification
in the link below, example #2 shows 3 circles drawn in SVG and having
the mix-blend-mode property.
mix-blend-mode example 2
I have reproduced this example below


circle {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
svg { 
  background-color:rgb(120,55,60);
}
<svg>
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="40" fill="lime"/>
  <circle cx="60" cy="80" r="40" fill="blue"/>
</svg>



I'm trying to apply the mix-blend-mode property in div elements and understand which properties I need to add to get the same result as with svg elements.
I reproduced the example without going through the svg elements, my goal is to reproduce the same result with div elements and their property, and understand how the display is calculated with the mix-blend-mode property .
(well I didn't reproduce circles but squares)


#container {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:rgb(120,55,60);
}
#carre1 {
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}
#carre2 {
  background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
  position:relative;
  top:-35px;
  left:26px;
}
#carre3 {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,255);
  position:relative;
  top:-65px;
  left:16px;
}
.carre {
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
<div id="container">
  <div class="carre" id="carre1"></div>
  <div class="carre" id="carre2"></div>
  <div class="carre" id="carre3"></div>
</div>



my question:
in this last example, with the div elements, what properties should be added to obtain the same result as with the SVG elements ?
ok...problem! the result is not the same depending on the browser:
with Chrome I have this:

with firefox :

I use firefox and that's why I asked the question. But I think it's chrome that's buggy, and that the difference between my example with squares and the example with circles is normal because it's missing a property
**
updated : maybe I understood, I say maybe
**
for the example with divs, I placed the

isolation:isolate

property, in an intermediate div#divForIsolate (and not in the same div that contained the background color).
And then, the result is the same with svg and with div. This would mean, perhaps, that the svg element contains the isolate property. If someone can confirm this for me, that would be welcome.


body {
  background-color:rgb(120,55,60);
}
.circle {
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
}

#divForIsolate {
  isolation:isolate;
}
.carre {
  mix-blend-mode:screen;
}
#carre1 {
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
}
#carre2 {
  background-color:rgb(0,255,0);
  position:relative;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  top:-80px;
  left:40px;
}
#carre3 {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,255);
  position:relative;
  top:-120px;
  left:20px;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
}
<svg>
  <circle class="circle" cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="red"/>
  <circle class="circle" cx="80" cy="40" r="40" fill="lime"/>
  <circle class="circle" cx="60" cy="80" r="40" fill="blue"/>
</svg>

<div id="divForIsolate">
  <div class="carre" id="carre1"></div>
  <div class="carre" id="carre2"></div>
  <div class="carre" id="carre3"></div>
</div>



In the link below, they say: the group must become isolated.
But what is the "group"?
https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#mix-blend-mode


did you consider the background of container? it's part of the blending process as well. Remove and see the difference again

@TemaniAfif, the background of container, rgb(120,55,60) , is the same in svg example and in div example, why the result is different?  the blending process is the same, so if the background color is the same why the difference at the end?

I suppose it's a Firefox bug with the SVG because on chrome both are the same and the div example in Firefox is also the same which is logical for me.

ok, I thought it was because the isolate property was missing somewhere, so I was trying to figure out that property...

It looks like that in Firefox, the svg element always establishes a stacking context. I can't see any reason why that's a requirement, so probably Firefox is in error on this point.

There's an existing firefox bug for SVG stacking context.

@Alohci   But it is precisely written in the specification that the mix-blend-mode property generates a stacking context. Here is a copy and pasted note of this specification <<Note: Applying a blendmode other than normal to the element must establish a new stacking context. This group must then be blended and composited with the stacking context that contains the element.>>

Right, but you haven't applied a non-normal mix-blend-mode to the svg element/#container element, only to the circle elements/.carre elements. If you force the svg element/#container element to establish a stacking context by applying isolation: isolate to them, you get a consistent result in both Firefox and Chrome. But it is consistently the result that is obtained from the svg element in Firefox.

@Alohci , I put the isolation:isolate property in the element/#container but it doesn't change anything. Can you show me?
